# Github all pull requests go to upstream instead of current fork

Tags: git, github

I am using `GitHub Enterprise Server 2.18.7`.

I have set the default branch in the branch settings to something other than master. However all my pull requests still default to upstream's master branch.

If that is not possible, is there a way to cut ties with upstream altogether? We do not plan on pushing any code upstream.

Comment: This is for github pull requests in particular. Not git pushes.

Comment: @SouradeepNanda And the answer, as hown below, is "no, unless you create a brand new repository"

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a new remote repository, which would be this time *not* a fork, but a new empty one.

From there, you can locally change the remote URL

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin /new/url
git push --mirror
```

In that new remote repo, any PR will not display `upstream/master`